# CSS tooltip hovering position issue in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, hover, position, tooltip

I found a full CSS tooltip to use in a new site. It works perfectly in Safari and Chrome. But only in Firefox, the tooltip keeps hovering to the far left of the DIV no matter where the link is on the page.

I found this question on this site that was extremely close, but did not give me the answer I needed.
[CSS Tooltip hovering position issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510710/css-tooltip-hovering-position-issue)

Could it bug in Firefox, or is there additional code i need to add for Firefox specifically?

I did make sure relative and absolute positioning were correct according to rules on setting that up. I am still very new to all of this. So any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
a.tip2 {
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
}

a.tip2 span {display: none;}

a.tip2:hover span {
display: block;
position: absolute; 
padding: .5em;
content: attr(title);
min-width: 120px;
text-align: center;
width: auto;
height: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
top: -32px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;    
color: #fff;
font-size: .86em;
}

a.tip2:hover span:after {
position: absolute;
display: block;
content: "";  
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8) transparent transparent transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px;
height:0;
width:0;
position:absolute;
bottom: -20px;
left:1em;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example where we could see it live? Try [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: have you tried setting a left element to the a.tip2:hover span css? I believe Firefox requires at least two position declarations (top or bottom and left or right) to work correctly

Comment: animuson - Unfortunately, I do not.

Comment: LifeInTheGrey - That worked!!! Thank you so much. I'll keep that requirement in mind next time. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem with Firefox positioning the hover image in a different location than IE, Chrome, and Safari.

I changed the css specifically for Firefox:

```
/*Firefox*/
@-moz-document url-prefix()
{
a.enlarge:hover span{top: 250px; left: 20px;}
}
```

whereas for the other browsers I am using top: -200px